# why static initialisation and constructor behavior is different in this program.?

Tags: c++

when i run the below program with constructor defination then output is -1 after the execution of last pop function.

```
#define SIZE 100
class stack
{
private:
    int tos;
    int arr[SIZE];
public:
    stack(){tos=0;}
    int push(int);
    int pop();
};

int stack::push(int i)
{
    if(tos==SIZE)
        {cout<<"stack is full\n";}
        arr[tos]=i;
        tos++;
        return 0;
}
int stack::pop ()
{
    if(tos==0)
        {cout<<"stack is empty\n";}
        tos--;
        return arr[tos];
}

int main()
{
    stack stack1;
    stack1.push(1);
    stack1.push(2);
    stack1.push(3);
    cout<<stack1.pop();
    cout<<stack1.pop();
    cout<<stack1.pop();
    cout<<stack1.pop();
    return 0;
}
```

But the same program gives the junk value when i try to run with static initialisation.why??

```
#define SIZE 100
class stack
{
    private:
        static int tos;
        int arr[SIZE];
    public:
        int push(int);
        int pop();
};

int stack :: tos = 0;
int stack::push(int i)
{
    if(tos==SIZE)
    {cout<<"stack is full\n";}
    arr[tos]=i;
    tos++;
    return 0;
}
int stack::pop ()
{
    if(tos==0)
    {cout<<"stack is empty\n";}
    tos--;
    return arr[tos];
}

int main()
{
    stack stack1;
    stack1.push(1);
    stack1.push(2);
    stack1.push(3);
    cout<<stack1.pop();
    cout<<stack1.pop();
    cout<<stack1.pop();
    cout<<stack1.pop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "static member" != "static initialization" - your comparison makes no sense because the second program is simply utterly wrong.

Comment: Both are utterly wrong IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of undefined behavior. When you push or pop, you check that it's okay, but then continue with the operation even it it's not.

So when you push three times, and the pop four, you will index your array with a negative index in the `pop` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your both programs has the same mistakes:

```
int stack::pop ()
{
    if(tos==0)
    {cout<<"stack is empty\n";}
    tos--;
    return arr[tos];
}
```

You're trying to get an element out of bounds of array. This causes an Undefined Behavior. The same in the `push` function.

Answer (score 0):

Push and pop function should be changed as,

```
    #define SUCCESS 0
    #define FAILURE 1

    stack::stack(){tos=-1;}

    int stack::push(int i)
    {
        if(tos==SIZE)
        {
          cout<<"stack is full\n";
          return FAILURE;
        }
        else {
           arr[++tos]=i;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    int stack::pop ()
    {
       if(tos==-1)
       {
          cout<<"stack is empty\n";
          throw "Stack is Empty"; //Throw the exception, handle the exception in main
       }
       else 
       {
          return arr[tos--];
       }
    }
```